# SSIS Kingswaysoft CRM Destination Update Error .. ExecuteMultiple Request batch size exceeds the maximum.. Err -2147220715

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm, kingswaysoft

When using a flat file to update a field on the account entity, no matter what I put in for Batch size I get that number of rows that get the below error:

> ExecuteMultiple Request batch size exceeds the maximum batch size allowed!(Error Code: -2147220715)

For example, I'm using a file with 450 updates.  If I leave the batch size at 200, I get 200 of the above errors and the rest process fine.  If I set the batch size to 10, I get 10 errors and the rest are fine.

If I select the Enable Multithreaded Writing, I still get the same results even if I update the "use up to" to more than one.

I know I could just set the batch size to 450 or more, but when this runs for real, we'll need to update 10s of thousands.

Using CRM Destination V9.2

Am I missing a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

For this error message, are you currently using “**Update All**” as the **Handling of Multiple Matches**? If that is the case, this might be the cause of this problem, since you have too many duplicates in your target system that matches the input. You can either remove those duplicates or you can change the option to “**Update One**” to handle this situation. Hope this helps.